# Grok pattern for date

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have date in my logs as :

> 08 Jul 2016 08:58:07,258 ...

Currently I am using :

```
%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{MONTH}[T ]%{YEAR}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})[T ]...
```

to parse it.

How can I convert this into date type. I know how to use 'date' to do so when we have an existing grok pattern but how to do that in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom pattern:

```
(?<log_timestamp>%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{MONTH}[T ]%{YEAR}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}[T ])
```

With this, you'll have a field `log_timestamp` you can give to the `date` filter.

Or you can use the `ruby` filter to concatenate all the fields in one to give to the `date` filter.

Comment: Will taking the date part of my log message into a field "Date" using GREEDYDATA and then using this "Date" field in `date` filter like `match => [ "Date", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]` work ?

Comment: @PuRaK If the content of the `Date` field match the `"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS"` pattern, it will work, whatever the method used to create the field.